# Convert binary number to ASCII code with STM32F446RE

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32, gnu-assembler, cortex-m

I want to know if there is a way to convert a binary or decimal number into an ASCII code in assembly using STM32F446RE.

More precisely, if I have  an array like this:

```
Tab: .byte  01101000,01100101,01101100,01101100,01101111
```

what should I do to have a new array like this:

```
new_Tab: .asciz  h,e,l,l,o
```

or a new word like:

```
new_word: .asciz  hello
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do, with some example input and output? The term "binary or decimal number" is a bit confusing. Also, are you looking for a specific instruction, or just an algorithm? What research have you done so far?

Comment: manually or programmatically? and what does this have to do with st or the cortexm or anything like that, or even assembly language for that matter...

Comment: `01101000` is a large decimal number.  Did you mean `0b01101000`?  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Integers.html.

Comment: If you write your constants correctly, `.byte  0b01101000,0b01100101,0b01101100,0b01101100,0b01101111` already is exactly equivalent to `.ascii "hello"` or `.byte 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'`.  (Note .ascii, not .asciz, unless you put a `, 0` element at the end.)  Try it, and look at a hexdump of the .rodata section of your object file, e.g. from objdump.